# Problem running acme-companion when setting up nginx-proxy

Tags: lets-encrypt, acme.sh

I'm trying to run a fairly simple docker stack, but for some reason it is failing to register certificates.

My composer:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    network_mode: bridge

  acme-companion:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-acme
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    network_mode: bridge

volumes:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  dhparam:
  certs:
  acme:
```

This is my log from **acme-companion**

```
Info: running acme-companion version v2.1.0-25-g7f1b754,
Generating a RSA private key,
...................................................................++++,
...........................................................................................................................................................................................++++,
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/default.key.new',
-----,
1996071824:error:0D0D90AD:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TIME_adj:error getting time:crypto/asn1/a_time.c:330:,
Info: a default key and certificate have been created at /etc/nginx/certs/default.key and /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt.,
Warning: /etc/nginx/certs/default.key does not exist. Skipping ownership and permissions check.,
Warning: /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt does not exist. Skipping ownership and permissions check.,
Info: Custom Diffie-Hellman group found, generation skipped.,
Reloading nginx proxy (nginx-proxy)...,
2021/09/13 08:54:28 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification '',
2021/09/13 08:54:28 [notice] 91#91: signal process started,
2021/09/13 08:54:29 Generated '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 4 containers,
2021/09/13 08:54:29 Running '/app/signal_le_service',
2021/09/13 08:54:29 Watching docker events,
2021/09/13 08:54:29 Contents of /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification '/app/signal_le_service',
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Please refer to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code: 6,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Can not init api.,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Registering account: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Please refer to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code: 6,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Could not get nonce, let's try again.,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Please refer to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code: 6,
[Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970] Could not get nonce, let's try again.
```

So error code 6 should be **CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST** but I'm not sure exactly what it can't resolve. This server has a connection and everything else seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on to this issue then here is the fix. It seems to affect alpine version 3.13 and probably other ones.

https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/135